# SEO for static content website

Tags: seo, ranking, google-ranking

We have a website that has around 15 content pages which is same for every page. It cannot be changed because it's about product information and services information etc. So, those pages' content we cannot change.

What should I do to get my site constantly updated? Should I start a blog for my website that will be within my own website and I start posting content related to my business? Will that do?

In short I am confused about if a website is product based, how to get it ranked higher in Google?

Comment: I'm confused. Why must pages be exactly the same if you're trying to update a site? Updating something means something has to change.  Maybe post some pictures on what can and can't be changed and what you expect to achieve. And the objective is to make content that makes users happy, not just search engines happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SEO if you are going to use wordpress then you can use Yoast SEO plugin as suggested by @Manoj.

Next thing is search engine always love fresh content whenever it crawl your site if finds for popular keywords and fresh content so I would suggest you to keep fresh content for your site.

Blog is really good way for SEO so setup it and it will help you a lot if you manage it properly.

Your site will have products so you should update products /Add new products on some regular time interval. Also choose popular and competitive keywords for each product so it will help you better in SEO.

Comment: Okay, i will have to regularly `UPDATE` my website in terms of product adding and updating, and search engine will find keywords on every interval. Thanx @Helping Hands for to the point and satisfactory answer. And thanx @Manoj for Plugin advice.

Comment: @SoebSafi - cheers.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is perfect for introducing WordPress. With WordPress you can dynamically update the content of the website in a span of few seconds. The installation doesn't take more than 10 minutes.

Since it is a product based website, I would recommend using WordPress along with WooCommerce which is a free plugin within the system. There is not much technical knowledge required to manage it when compared to other frameworks and writing coding from scratch.

Comment: Thanx for the reply @Manoj Kumar, and you are right, i am already useing wordpress for my website. It is already build in wordpress platform. My question was from SEO's prospective. How will google know that my website is getting constantly updated. I want to get my rankings higher.

Comment: You can try installing Yoast SEO plugin. It will give an overview of what's missing in your site. Also analyze your site with Moz.com site explorer.

Comment: thanx i will install Yoast Plugin, but still i want to know about constantly updating content, as it  is not blog, how should i update it constantly like on weekly basis.

Comment: It is not dependent on the time period, mostly the quality of posts and kind of traffic is required.

Comment: Alright, i was not aware about the time period you mentioned. now what should i do to get my ranking higher in search if my website is of this kind. Shall i write blog post within my website, shall start blog commenting, or forum posting. If YES then on which type website shall i comment or which type of forum should i use. OR IF NO then what is the best alternate way.?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better for you to build up a new website. If your products is not too much, your website will not cost much. As other suggested..I also suggest you use WordPress to build your Ecommerce-website. Wordpress is one of simple CMS. So, it will help you to manage content easily. It's also really cheap to build up a WP site. You may use many free templates.
2. For SEO purpose (get high ranking with Google). You may use plugin for WP. there are a lot of plugins support SEO purpose. ex: all in one SEO, meta tags, robot, breakcrum... the installation of these plugins is also very simple. Remember that Google prefer fresh and unique content. if you don't have much experience about how to do SEO, you may ask support from SEOers around the Net (stackexchange is also a good place).

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions @Davidoff your answer is very explanatory.